# python tkinter Label ++1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

Hi I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class calculation_game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_user = Tk()
        self.screen_user.title("חישובים - מסך משתמש")
        self.screen_user.geometry("400x400+600+200")
        self.screen_user.resizable(False, False)

        self.x = 0

        self.points_user = Label(self.screen_user, text="הניקוד שלך הוא: ")
        self.points_user.place(x=290, y=370)
        self.points_text = Label(self.screen_user, text=self.x)
        self.points_text.place(x=252, y=370)


        self.button = Button(self.screen_user, text="שלח", command=lambda :self.select_lvl())
        self.button.place(x=180, y=230)

        self.text_name = StringVar()
        self.text_name = Entry(self.screen_user, justify='center')
        self.text_name.place(x=100, y=200)



        self.screen_user.mainloop()
```

I have this var: `self.x = 0`

I want add 1 to self.x if something good after I add 1 to var self.x

I want show this on the software with self.points_text

sorry in my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont quite understand your question but I believe you're trying to increment self.x by one if an event occurs

try using

```
self.x += 1
```

instead

Comment: When do you want to add to self.x, just saying something good happens isn't enough

Comment: I give you example:

self.screen_user = Tk()

z = 0
x = 2
y = 2

if x == y:
z += 1
self.points_text = Label(self.screen_user, text=z).pack()

I want to show the add in self.points_text too

Comment: so in the label you want the text to display {z, and x}? If that's the case replace text=z with text="%s%s" % (z, x)

Comment: TY for help and sorry on my English